# Oracle Error PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package

Can someone help me put my pl/sql procedure in a package? I've tried and I'm struggling with it:

This is what I have, for my package specification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE film_pkg
IS
title VARCHAR2(100);
PROCEDURE get_films(fname VARCHAR2);
END film_pkg;

--
```

This is my package body where im running into the problems:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY film_pkg
IS
   PROCEDURE get_films (fname    IN     film.title%TYPE,
                        r_date      OUT film.release_date%TYPE,
                        dur         OUT film.duration%TYPE)
   AS
   BEGIN
      SELECT release_date, duration
        INTO r_date, dur
        FROM FILM
       WHERE title = fname;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         r_date := '';
         dur := '';
   END get_films;
END film_pkg;
```

if anyone could help me fix the errors i'd appreciate it:

```
Error(4,11): PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'GET_FILMS' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your header and body procedure definitions don't match

In the header, you have:

```
PROCEDURE get_films(fname VARCHAR2);
```

Whereas in the body:

```
PROCEDURE get_films(fname IN film.title%type, 
   r_date OUT film.release_date%type, dur OUT film.duration%type)
```

You probably just need to update the header definition with the two additional OUT params?

**To Summarize**

- Ensure the header definition matches all parameters of the body implementation (number of parameters, names of parameters, order of parameters, and the parameter types)
- As per Alex's comment, do not mix and match the custom type (`film.title%type`) with the base type (`VARCHAR2`). Choose one or the other.

Comment: When I tried that I got the error in the pkg body:Error(4,11): PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'GET_FILMS' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body

Comment: @SqlNoob - `%type` is fine, but you have to use exactly the same declaration, you can't mix and match even if you know they are the same; did you make the spec `fname IN film.title%type` too, or leave that as `varchar`? The whole declaration has to be identical. (And you can't specify the size for a parameter, so `varchar2(50 byte)` would cause an error).

Comment: Also, remember to recompile the package header, i was struggling with this because I changed a procedure definiion to add error code out and i forgot to recompile the package header.

Answer (score 1):

"**parameter name** that was inside the procedure defined in the body did not match with the corresponding parameter name in the body."

Answer (score 0):

"subprogram or cursor 'M115_EDIT' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body"

I got this error while i was working on my project.the reason for this was the a parameter name that was inside the procedure defined in the body did not match with the corresponding parameter name in the body.

[my specification:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3BRG.png)

[my body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9bYo.png)

my market_code parameter is different in the body when compared with the specification where it is defined as sub_market_code.error occurred due to this difference.
i changed the sub_market_code parameter in the specification to market_code so that it matches with the body and this solved the problem mentioned above.

clearly 2 parameters that are mentioned in your body implementation of the procedure 'r_date' and 'dur' are not defined in the specification.error is due to this difference between the body and the specification.